# How to determine all permuations &| combinations in a hiearchical structure

Tags: c#, math, complexity-theory, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to figure a method for determining every possible combination of parent <> child relationship in an imaginary hierarchy. (Combination or permutation - once you've figured out all the permutations you have also got the possible combinations too).

**Constraints**

The relationships between nodes can be 1:1, 1:many or many to 1 but never many:many.
Each node in the hierarchy can have 1 of 3 properties attached to it's relationship when considered in their relationship to any other given ancestor or parent node.

Eg

A -> B   (A is an ancestor of B)

A(X) -> B   (A is an ancestor of B with property X)

A(Y) -> B   (A is an ancestor of B with property Y)

A(Z) -> B   (A is an ancestor of B with property Z)

All 4 above relationships are valid outcomes.

Similarly;

A & B -> C  (A and B are both ancestors of C)

A (X) & B(X) -> C  (A and B are both ancestors of C, with A having X and B having X)

A (X) & B(Y) -> C  (Ditto, but now A & B have X & Y properties in this example)

The above 3 are also perfectly valid.

**So in pseudo code;**

foreach (node someNode in totalNodePopulation)

{try every combination SomeCombination with every ancestor | child }

foreach (somecombination in combinations)

{ determine all 3 variants}

This code below determines all combinations of simple list of Ints;

```
public Dictionary<int, List<int>> shouldReturnAllPossibleCombinations(List<int> number)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> combos = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        double count = Math.Pow(2, number.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            List<int> itemsInThisCombo = new List<int>();

            string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(number.Count, '0');
            for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[j] == '1')
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(number[j]);
                    itemsInThisCombo.Add(number[j]);
                }
            }
            combos.Add(i, itemsInThisCombo);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return combos;
    }
```

But how to then improve it to cope with the "dimensionality" of the variants?

Any ideas / pointers much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "one can be redacted back to the other" - redact (verb) __"censor or obscure (part of a text) for legal or security purposes."__ Is that the word you meant?

Comment: Sorry - bad English. I meant that if you've managed to write a method to figure out all the possible permutations, you have by inference determined all the combinations too. So one wipes out the other.

Comment: Ar X and Y properties of the nodes? Or properties of the relationships?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Hi - they're properties of the node. Or another way of looking at it, is that eg node "A"  (which is just one node in of itself) could be fed into the algorithm as Ax and Ay and Az separately (ie, 'pretend' that A exists three times). Thanks for the comment - I'll edit my original question to make that clear since it's slightly ambiguous as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
public class Node {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

public static List<(Node node1, Node node2, string relationship)> PossibleCombinations(List<Node> lst) {
    var ret = new List<(Node node1, Node node2, string relationship)>();
    var relationships = new string[] { null, "X", "Y", "Z" };
    foreach (var node1 in lst) {
        foreach (var node2 in lst) {
            if (node1==node2) { continue; }
            foreach (var relationship in relationships) {
                ret.Add((node1, node2, relationship));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var lst = new List<Node>() {
    new Node() {Name="A"},
    new Node() {Name="B"},
    new Node() {Name="C"}
};
foreach (var node in lst) {
    foreach (var combination_variant in PossibleCombinations(lst)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{node} - {combination_variant});
    }
}
```

AFAICT this is a reflection of your original psuedocode description:

> ```
> foreach (node someNode in totalNodePopulation)
>     {try every combination SomeCombination with every ancestor | child }
>     foreach (somecombination in combinations)
>        { determine all 3 variants}
> ```

Comment: @zev-sptiz Hi - thanks, that's great since it iterates the examples i gave and contends for the variants. The hierarchy however is just that: A-> B-> C for example. It could be nth levels "deep" so to speak. I suspect your code could be tweaked to deal with that?

Comment: @JonathanCobb Is the hierarchy explicitly defined? Or is it simply that each node in the set is the parent of the one after it, and the child of the one before?

Comment: Thanks - the hierarchy starts explicitly, for example A&B -> ancestor of C which is ancestor of D&E&F and E has eg 4 descendants of it's own. Then.....how many combinations of nodes can be made out of that hierarchy? it could be totally flat ABCDE, it could be E > ABCD or it could be C>D&E>A &B etc etc. That's the real challenge - your current answer works across one "level". Does that explanation help?

Comment: @JonathanCobb I've updated my answer; is this any closer? Perhaos if you include some kind of diagram in your question?